# Push notification to display a ViewController with Animation in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, push-notification, core-animation

I have a local push notification on iOS that when user taps on the notification, it will bring up a `ViewController`. Inside of the `viewDidAppear` method of this controller, I start an animation. The problem for me is when the local push notification shows either when app is at foreground (screen lock) or background, I have to tap really fast to see the animation. Most of the times, can only see the last frame of it. It seems put animation code in `viewDidAppear` does not help. Where shall I put this animation start?

Comment: Did you try to set a delay to your animation?